# What is the best caching option?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have some data which is obtained from an API which I display via a master-detail web page. The data I receive from the API is in JSON format and I currently cache a serialised version of this to disk. All files are stored in a single folder. The file is used for a maximum of 1 week as new content is released every week. There can be up to a maximum of 40,000 files. Each file is about 12kb and a guid is used as the filename.

What is the best caching strategy?

1. Keep as is.
2. Store the raw JSON instead of serialised data.
3. Replace the disk caching solution with a NoSQL solution like Redis.
4. Organise the files into folders
5. Use faster serialization / deserialization techniques

Comment: The total space is 12KB X 40,000 = 0.5GB. With a large disk cache, you might not have to worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge RAM then in order to retrieve the data faster you can avoid serialization and de serialization and keep the data directly in Redis as key value pair.